# Getting django to work with apache/mod_wsgi... any ideas?

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have read several tutorials, but I just can't this to work. My apache config file looks like this (with the important few lines at the bottom):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel warn

WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi/ /neuroling/projects/lnldb/lnldbproject/lnldb.wsgi
<Directory /neuroling/projects/lnldb/lnldbproject/>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My lnldb.wsgi file looks like this:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/neuroling/projects/lnldb'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

path = '/neuroling/projects/lnldb/lnldbproject'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'lnldbproject.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Now if I go to [MY_IP_ADDRESS]/wsgi with my broswer, I see this:

Using the URLconf defined in lnldbproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.

Fair enough, I haven't really given it a URL. But at least lnldb.wsgi is getting called.

But I want to see the admin, so I go to [MY_IP_ADDRESS]/wsgi/admin, and I just get:

Not Found
The requested URL /wsgi/admin was not found on this server.

Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong, I'm sure it's something rather simple...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does it work if you try `/wsgi/admin/` - ie with a trailing slash?

Comment: No, doesn't seem to... thanks.

Comment: Don't think this will fix your problem, but in the wsgi file, for `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = ` shouldn't it just be `'settings'` since you are already in the lnldbproject? I would suggest verifying that the WSGI file is actually connecting, by creating a view that just has `return HttpResponse('Works')` and add a url list for /wsgi/ to urls.py, like `url(r'^wsgi/$', 'path.to.view'),` to make sure that connection is good.

Comment: I read that it should be project.settings, but I think you're right that it would work with just settings. Well, I got the problem solved thanks to the answer below... thanks for your input too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi/ /neuroling/projects/lnldb/lnldbproject/lnldb.wsgi
```

to:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi /neuroling/projects/lnldb/lnldbproject/lnldb.wsgi
```

You should not have a trailing slash on mount point when mounted at sub URL for a start.

Comment: Awesome, it works. Thanks so much. I knew it must be something small like this, but I just could not figure it out. THANK YOU.